# Replacing a specific character if it is inside a string that matches a pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to use regex to replace a specific character inside a string if it matches a pattern?
For example I want to replace `\` with `X` if it is inside two `$` characters, otherwise it should remain unchanged.

```
 $some\string here inside$ and [some here \out side]
```

and what I expect to have in output is

```
$someXstring here inside$ and [some here \out side]
```

`re.sub(r'\$*\\*\$', 'X', b)` replaces `$` with `X`. How should I do this with one `re.sub` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` with `re.sub` using `str.replace` to replace any `\\` that matches your pattern

```
s = "$some\string here inside$ and [some here \out side]"
import re

print(re.sub(r"\$.*\\.*\$",lambda  x: x.group().replace("\\","X"),s))
$someXstring here inside$ and [some here \out side]
```

Comment: Appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regexless solution:

```
s = r'$some\string here inside$ and [some here \out side]'

def solution(s):
    inside = False
    for c in s:
        if c == '$':
            inside = not inside
            yield c
        elif inside and c == '\\':
            yield 'X'
        else:
            yield c


print(''.join(solution(s)))
```

I know some explanation would be welcome, but at the moment I have no idea what could I explain.